# What is the best practice to send unlimited email using PHP

Tags: email, postfix-mta

We have a web site basically send daily 10K email notifications to users. I tried to use Google Apps but reach their daily limit quickly and then I create multiple accounts on godaddy and buy smtp relays (daily 250) to provide email notifications to our users..

- What is the best practice to provide it without being marked spam and small budget?
- Maybe I need to install postfix and dovecot?

Comment: would this happen to be for sending `'important business emails'` to users that did not request it?

Comment: i think you could ask this question on superusers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4798141/sendgrid-vs-postmark-vs-amazon-ses-and-other-email-smtp-api-providers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sending that many emails from a single server will get it blacklisted pretty quickly I should say. Maybe you should look into some of the big name SMTP services such as [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com), [Mailjet](http://mailjet.com) or [Postmarkapp](http://postmarkapp.com) They're not free but usually pretty cheap, depending on volume.

Provided your email sending needs are genuine (i.e. not spam) these platforms can get pretty good at making sure your emails are not marked as spam. However if you are sending spam, you're going to get blacklisted anyway, so just rent a botnet, that's what they're for ;)